# Set div height to inner div with position: absolute in combination with CSS3 transitions

Tags: html, css

I've created some tiles with CSS3. Inside every tile div, there is an image and some text. The text is displayed when you hover over the image.

**The tiles can be seen in [this CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KiyHl).**

However, as you can see, the tiles automatically take the height of tile-text, but I want them to adjust to the hieght of the image. I know you can do this by setting position: relative instead of absolute, but then the hover doens't work anymore.

Does anyone know how to fix this? I'm really lost, so it would be greatly appreciated!

**P.S. Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to use Javascript or JQuery for this project.**

Comment: The text tile seems to disappear after hovering for ~1 second, is this intentional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had the right idea, you just overcomplicated some of the code, which was causing conflicts. Here's a fresh version of your codePen, with it much more simplified. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mAirH

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the `overflow: hidden;` from `#tile-container .tile` then you'll get the right height. You will, however, have to adjust the width to make up for the removal of the overflow.

Update: If you add

```
*{
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

then the width is fine as well.

Here's an updated pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iAubK